# Gulp 4 / Undertaker issue - Custom registry must have `init` function

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to run gulp and I am getting this issue from undertaker:

```
→ gulp serve
[20:13:12] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[20:13:12] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/clean.js
[20:13:12] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/deploy.js
[20:13:12] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/icons.js
[20:13:13] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/images.js
[20:13:13] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/scripts.js
[20:13:13] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/serve.js
[20:13:13] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/siteAssets.js
[20:13:13] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/siteTemplates.js
[20:13:13] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/styles.js
[20:13:13] Loading /Users/Sites/my-site/gulp/tasks/templates.js

/Users/Sites/my-site/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/validateRegistry.js:34
      throw err;
      ^
AssertionError: Custom registry must have `init` function
    at validateRegistry (/Users/Sites/my-site/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/validateRegistry.js:28:5)
    at Gulp.registry (/Users/Sites/my-site/node_modules/undertaker/lib/registry.js:18:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Sites/my-site/gulpfile.babel.js:11:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at normalLoader (/Users/Sites/my-site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Sites/my-site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

And here is my gulp version:

```
→ gulp -v
[20:32:38] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[20:32:38] CLI version 0.4.0
[20:32:38] Local version 4.0.0-alpha.1
```

Which gulp? This gulp:

```
→ which gulp
/usr/local/bin/gulp
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what the issue is. I have scoured the web and found this, which is most certainly the same issue:

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1834

However, this person never seemed to solve the issue and all of those proposed solutions haven't worked for me.

Anyone else run into this or a similar issue with undertaker registry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I actually fixed it with the help of a co-worker by changing the gulp-hub version in my package.json from

```
"gulp-hub": "frankwallis/gulp-hub#4.0",
```

to

```
"gulp-hub": "frankwallis/gulp-hub#registry-init",
```

and that fixed it.

Comment: For a more recent commit: "gulp-hub": "frankwallis/gulp-hub#4.1.0"